# Foliation by complex hypersurfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, foliations

I am learning about the Levi flat hypersurfaces. Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be a real smooth hypersurface, i.e. for every point $p$ in $M$ there is an open set $U_p$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ containing $p$ and a smooth function $r: U_p \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $grad(r)$ does not vanish on $U_p$ and $M \cap U_p=\{z \in U_p : r(z)=0\}$. Now, $M$ is said to be Levi flat if the Levi form of $M$ vanishes. Mathematically, the following holds:
(Levi-flat condition) $\overset{2}{\underset{i, j=1}{\sum}}\bar{a}_ia_j\frac{\partial ^2 r}{\partial \bar{z}_i\partial z_j}|_p=0$ whenever $\overset{2}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}a_i\frac{\partial r}{\partial z_i}|_p=0$ for all $p \in M$.

But I came across the following characterization for Levi-flat hypersurface  which seems to be easier for checking:

[image]

Can someone explain what do we mean by “foliation” of $M$ by complex manifolds? I request to provide any suggestions/references for this topic.

Comment: Are you asking what a general foliation is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation ?

Comment: For foliations in general, Candel and Conlon is the canonical reference, though I believe they stick to the real case.

Comment: @anomaly I want to understand what does foliation mean in this case only. Is it like a covering map?

Comment: Not really, no. The intuition for a foliation on a manifold $X$ is something like the collection of spaces $M_t = f^{-1}(t)$ for a fixed, suitably nice function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$. You should look at the wikipedia page, though; it's a complicated concept, and not something I can give much detail on in comments (and for a larger but still general answer, I'm not sure I have anything more to say that what wikipedia or Candel and Conlon would give.)

Comment: @anomaly Is the set $M=\{(z_1+\overline{z_2}z_3,  z_2+\overline{z_1}z_3, z_3 ) \in \mathbb{C}^3 : |z_1|+|z_2|=1, |z_3|<1, z_1 \ne 0, z_2 \ne 0  \}$ a Levi flat smooth hypersurface? $M$ is a smooth hypersurface because for any $p \in M$, choose $U_p=\{(z_1, z_2, z_3) \in \mathbb{C}^3 :  z_1 \ne 0, z_2 \ne 0, |z_3|<1\}$ (which is an open set in $\mathbb{C}^3$ containing $M$ and so, $p$) and a smooth function $r(z_1, z_2, z_3)=|z_1|+|z_2|-1$ on $U_p$ with gradient of $r$ non-vanishing on $U_p$. Also, $M \cap U_p=\{z \in U_p: r(z)=0 \}$. How to check Levi flatness of $M$, whether or not if it is.